# How to use djoser with djangorestframework

Tags: django-rest-framework, djoser

I am trying to connect djoser, but when I go via the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/ I cannot see **the root endpoints**. I cannot understand why It doesn't work.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'cars_app',
'djoser', 
 ]
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/v1/base-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
path('api/v1/cars_app/', include('cars_app.urls')),
path('api/v1/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
path('api/v1/auth_token/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]
```

What I see via the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
"users": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/users/"
}
```

What may be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. there is nothing wrong with your code. Django returns the first matching path from the URL, which is user here. Endpoints that you see in the browsable API are provided by router and come from ViewSet views. If you want it for class-based views(ListAPIView, etc) you can check this link

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/#creating-an-endpoint-for-the-root-of-our-api